# Geohash library in C++17

Tags: c++, geospatial

GeoHash library in C++17

- no allocations and no std::strings. It uses fixed buffer `GeoHash::buffer_t`.
- optimized nearby search, if possible, it search 2x2 or 2x3 cells, instead of 3x9 cells `GeoHash::nearbyCells`.
- suppose to work correctly on latitudes over 65-70' where the geohash cell is really "narrow".

Here is the code:
https://github.com/nmmmnu/geohash/

---

**geohash.h**

```
#ifndef GEOHASH_H_
#define GEOHASH_H_

#include <cstdint>
#include <array>
#include <string_view>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

namespace GeoHash {
    constexpr static size_t MAX_SIZE    = 12;

    using buffer_t = std::array<char, 32>;

    // ------------------------------

    struct Point{
        double lat;
        double lon;

        constexpr Point fix() const{
            auto _ = [](double x){
                constexpr size_t p = 1'00'000;

                return round(x * p) / p;
            };

            return { _(lat), _(lon) };
        }
    };

    struct GeoSphere;

    struct Rectangle{
        Point sw;
        Point ne;

        constexpr auto n_lat() const{
            return ne.lat;
        };

        constexpr auto s_lat() const{
            return sw.lat;
        };

        constexpr auto e_lon() const{
            return ne.lon;
        };

        constexpr auto w_lon() const{
            return sw.lon;
        };

        // ------------------------------

        constexpr Point ne_p() const{
            return { n_lat(), e_lon() };
        };

        constexpr Point nw_p() const{
            return { n_lat(), w_lon() };
        };

        constexpr Point se_p() const{
            return { s_lat(), e_lon() };
        };

        constexpr Point sw_p() const{
            return { s_lat(), w_lon() };
        };

        // ------------------------------

        constexpr Point center() const{
            return {
                (sw.lat + ne.lat) / 2,
                (sw.lon + ne.lon) / 2
            };
        }

        // ------------------------------

        double height(GeoSphere const &sphere) const;
        double width(GeoSphere const &sphere) const;
        double area(GeoSphere const &sphere) const;
    };

    enum class Direction : uint8_t{
        n = 0,
        s = 1,
        e = 2,
        w = 3
    };

    // ------------------------------

    struct GeoSphere{
        std::string_view    sphere;

        std::string_view    units;

        double          radius;

        double cells[12] {
            CELLS_ABSOLUTE[ 0] * radius, //  1
            CELLS_ABSOLUTE[ 1] * radius, //  2
            CELLS_ABSOLUTE[ 2] * radius, //  3
            CELLS_ABSOLUTE[ 3] * radius, //  4
            CELLS_ABSOLUTE[ 4] * radius, //  5
            CELLS_ABSOLUTE[ 5] * radius, //  6
            CELLS_ABSOLUTE[ 6] * radius, //  7
            CELLS_ABSOLUTE[ 7] * radius, //  8
            CELLS_ABSOLUTE[ 8] * radius, //  9
            CELLS_ABSOLUTE[ 9] * radius, // 10
            CELLS_ABSOLUTE[10] * radius, // 11
            CELLS_ABSOLUTE[11] * radius  // 12
        };

    public:
        constexpr static double RADIUS_EARTH_KM     = 6371;
        constexpr static double RADIUS_EARTH_MI     = 3956;

    private:
        constexpr static double CELL_SHRINK_FACTOR  = 0.6666;

        constexpr static double CELL_SHRINK = CELL_SHRINK_FACTOR / RADIUS_EARTH_KM;

        constexpr static inline double CELLS_ABSOLUTE[12] {
            4'992.600   * CELL_SHRINK, // 1
              624.100   * CELL_SHRINK, // 2
              156.100   * CELL_SHRINK, // 3
               19.500   * CELL_SHRINK, // 4
                4.900   * CELL_SHRINK, // 5
                0.609'4 * CELL_SHRINK, // 6
                0.152'4 * CELL_SHRINK, // 7
                0.019'0 * CELL_SHRINK, // 8
                0.004'8 * CELL_SHRINK, // 9
                0.000'595   * CELL_SHRINK, // 10
                0.000'149   * CELL_SHRINK, // 11
                0.000'019   * CELL_SHRINK  // 12
        };
    };

    constexpr GeoSphere EARTH_KM        { "Earth",  "km",   GeoSphere::RADIUS_EARTH_KM  };
    constexpr GeoSphere EARTH_METERS    { "Earth",  "m",    EARTH_KM.radius * 1000      };

    constexpr GeoSphere EARTH_MI        { "Earth",  "mi",   GeoSphere::RADIUS_EARTH_MI  };
    constexpr GeoSphere EARTH_YD        { "Earth",  "yd",   EARTH_MI.radius * 1760      };

    constexpr GeoSphere MOON_KM     { "Moon",   "km",   1737.1              };
    constexpr GeoSphere MOON_METERS     { "Moon",   "m",    MOON_KM.radius * 1000       };

    constexpr GeoSphere MARS_KM     { "Mars",   "km",   3389.5              };
    constexpr GeoSphere MARS_METERS     { "Mars",   "m",    MARS_KM.radius * 1000       };

    // ------------------------------

    struct HashVector{
        constexpr auto begin() const{
            return data;
        }

        constexpr auto end() const{
            return data + size;
        }

    private:
        friend HashVector nearbyCells(double, double, double, GeoSphere const &);
        friend HashVector nearbyCells(std::string_view) noexcept;

        std::string_view    data[9];
        size_t          size;

        buffer_t        buffer[9];
    };

    // ------------------------------

    std::string_view encode(double lat, double lon, size_t precision, buffer_t &buffer) noexcept;

    inline auto encode(Point p, size_t precision, buffer_t &buffer){
        return encode(p.lat, p.lon, precision, buffer);
    }

    inline std::string encode(double lat, double lon, size_t precision){
        buffer_t buffer;

        return std::string{
            encode(lat, lon, precision, buffer)
        };
    }

    Rectangle decode(std::string_view hash);

    std::string_view adjacent(std::string_view geohash, Direction direction, buffer_t &buffer) noexcept;

    [[deprecated]]
    HashVector nearbyCells(std::string_view hash) noexcept;

    // ------------------------------

    double distance_radians(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) noexcept;

    inline double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2, GeoSphere const &sphere){
        auto _ = [](double degree){
            // toRadians
            constexpr double one_deg = M_PI / 180;
            return one_deg * degree;
        };

        return distance_radians(_(lat1), _(lon1), _(lat2), _(lon2)) * sphere.radius;
    }

    inline auto distance(Point p1, Point p2, GeoSphere const &sphere){
        return distance(p1.lat, p1.lon, p2.lat, p2.lon, sphere);
    }

    // ------------------------------

    HashVector nearbyCells(double lat, double lon, double radius, GeoSphere const &sphere);

    inline auto nearbyCells(Point p, double radius, GeoSphere const &sphere){
        return nearbyCells(p.lat, p.lon, radius, sphere);
    }

    // ------------------------------

    inline double Rectangle::height(GeoSphere const &sphere) const{
    //  return distance(sw.lat, sw.lon, ne.lat, sw.lon, sphere);
        return distance(ne_p(), se_p(), sphere);
    }

    inline double Rectangle::width(GeoSphere const &sphere) const{
    //  return distance(sw.lat, sw.lon, sw.lat, ne.lon, sphere);
        return distance(ne_p(), nw_p(), sphere);
    }

    inline double Rectangle::area(GeoSphere const &sphere) const{
        return width(sphere) * height(sphere);
    }
}

#endif
```

---

**geohash.c**

```
#include "geohash.h"

#include <cassert>
#include <stdexcept>


namespace GeoHash {
    // based on https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/geohash.html

    constexpr double LAT_MIN        =  -90;
    constexpr double LAT_MAX        =   90;
    constexpr double LON_MIN        = -180;
    constexpr double LON_MAX        =  180;

    constexpr inline static std::string_view BASE32 = "0123456789bcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz"; // geohash-specific Base32 map

    // ------------------------------

    std::string_view encode(double lat, double lon, size_t precision, buffer_t &buffer) noexcept{
        assert(precision > 0 && precision <= MAX_SIZE);

        size_t  ixb = 0;    // index of the buffer
        size_t  idx = 0;    // index into base32 map
        uint8_t bit = 0;    // each char holds 5 bits

        auto evenBit = true;

        auto latMin = LAT_MIN;
        auto latMax = LAT_MAX;
        auto lonMin = LON_MIN;
        auto lonMax = LON_MAX;

        while (ixb < precision){
            if (evenBit){
                // bisect E-W longitude
                auto const lonMid = (lonMin + lonMax) / 2;

                if (lon >= lonMid){
                    idx    = idx * 2 + 1;
                    lonMin = lonMid;
                } else {
                    idx    = idx * 2;
                    lonMax = lonMid;
                }
            }else{
                // bisect N-S latitude
                auto const latMid = (latMin + latMax) / 2;

                if (lat >= latMid){
                    idx    = idx * 2 + 1;
                    latMin = latMid;
                } else {
                    idx    = idx * 2;
                    latMax = latMid;
                }
            }

            evenBit = !evenBit;

            if (++bit == 5){
                // 5 bits gives us a character, append it and start over
                buffer[ixb++] = BASE32[idx];
                bit = 0;
                idx = 0;
            }
        }

        buffer[ixb] = '\0';

        return std::string_view{ buffer.data(), ixb };
    }

    Rectangle decode(std::string_view hash){
        assert(hash.size() > 0 && hash.size() <= MAX_SIZE);

        auto evenBit = true;

        auto latMin = LAT_MIN;
        auto latMax = LAT_MAX;
        auto lonMin = LON_MIN;
        auto lonMax = LON_MAX;

        for (size_t i = 0; i < hash.size(); ++i){
            auto const chr = hash[i];
            auto const idx = BASE32.find(chr, 0);

            if (idx == BASE32.npos)
                throw std::logic_error("Invalid geohash");

            for (ssize_t n = 4; n >= 0; --n){
                auto const bitN = (idx >> n) & 1;

                if (evenBit){
                    // longitude
                    auto const lonMid = (lonMin + lonMax) / 2;

                    if (bitN){
                        lonMin = lonMid;
                    }else{
                        lonMax = lonMid;
                    }
                }else{
                    // latitude
                    auto const latMid = (latMin + latMax) / 2;

                    if (bitN){
                        latMin = latMid;
                    }else{
                        latMax = latMid;
                    }
                }

                evenBit = !evenBit;
            }
        }

        return {
            Point{ latMin, lonMin },
            Point{ latMax, lonMax }
        };
    }

    namespace{

        std::string_view adjacent_calc_(size_t const size, Direction direction_, buffer_t &buffer){
            // based on github.com/davetroy/geohash-js

            constexpr static std::string_view neighbour[4][2] {
                { "p0r21436x8zb9dcf5h7kjnmqesgutwvy", "bc01fg45238967deuvhjyznpkmstqrwx" },
                { "14365h7k9dcfesgujnmqp0r2twvyx8zb", "238967debc01fg45kmstqrwxuvhjyznp" },
                { "bc01fg45238967deuvhjyznpkmstqrwx", "p0r21436x8zb9dcf5h7kjnmqesgutwvy" },
                { "238967debc01fg45kmstqrwxuvhjyznp", "14365h7k9dcfesgujnmqp0r2twvyx8zb" }
            };

            constexpr static std::string_view border[4][2] {
                { "prxz",   "bcfguvyz"  },
                { "028b",   "0145hjnp"  },
                { "bcfguvyz",   "prxz"      },
                { "0145hjnp",   "028b"      }
            };

            auto const direction = static_cast<uint8_t>(direction_);
            auto const lastCh    = buffer[size - 1];
            auto const type      = size % 2;

            // check for edge-cases which don't share common prefix
            if (border[direction][type].find(lastCh) != std::string::npos && size - 1 > 0)
                adjacent_calc_(size - 1, direction_, buffer);

            // append letter for direction to parent
            buffer[size - 1] = BASE32[ neighbour[direction][type].find(lastCh) ];

            return { buffer.data(), size };
        }

    } // anonymous namespace

    std::string_view adjacent(std::string_view geohash, Direction direction, buffer_t &buffer) noexcept{
        assert(geohash.size() > 0 && geohash.size() <= MAX_SIZE);

        // copy into buffer
        std::copy(std::begin(geohash), std::end(geohash), std::begin(buffer));

        return adjacent_calc_(geohash.size(), direction, buffer);
    }

    double distance_radians(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) noexcept{
        // Haversine Formula
        double const delta_lon = lon2 - lon1;
        double const delta_lat = lat2 - lat1;

        double const result =
            pow(sin(delta_lat / 2), 2) +
            pow(sin(delta_lon / 2), 2) * cos(lat1) * cos(lat2)
        ;

        return 2 * asin(sqrt(result));
    }

    // ------------------------------

    namespace{

        size_t selectCellsSize_(double radius, GeoSphere const &sphere){
            if (radius > sphere.cells[0])
                return 0;

            size_t i = 0;
            for(auto &cell : sphere.cells){
                // works OK until lat = 60.0,
                // but we shrink the cells sizes by 66% so is OK until 70.0
                if (radius > cell)
                    break;
                ++i;
            }

            return i;
        }
    }

    HashVector nearbyCells(double lat, double lon, double radius, GeoSphere const &sphere){
        constexpr bool ENABLE_OPTIMIZATIONS = 1;

        HashVector v;

        auto const size = selectCellsSize_(radius, sphere);

        if (!size){
            v.size = 0;

            return v;
        }

        v.data[0] = encode(lat, lon, size, v.buffer[0]);

        // we can do this, but code becomes unreadable
        //
        // auto adj = [&v](size_t index, size_t src, Direction dir) mutable{
        //  v.data[index] = adjacent(v.data[src], dir, v.data[buffer]);
        // };

        if constexpr(ENABLE_OPTIMIZATIONS){
            auto const bbox = decode(v.data[0]);

            auto const bbox_w = bbox.width(sphere);
            auto const bbox_h = bbox.height(sphere);

            if (bbox_h > 2 * radius){
                auto const bbox_center = bbox.center();

                if (bbox_w > 2 * radius){
                    // OPTIMIZED - 2 x 2 = 4

                    v.size = 4;

                    if (lat < bbox_center.lat){
                        // north
                        if (lon < bbox_center.lon){
                            // north west

                            v.data[1] = adjacent(v.data[0], Direction::n, v.buffer[1]);
                            v.data[2] = adjacent(v.data[0], Direction::w, v.buffer[2]);
                            v.data[3] = adjacent(v.data[1], Direction::w, v.buffer[3]);

                            return v;
                        }else{
                            // north east

                            v.data[1] = adjacent(v.data[0], Direction::n, v.buffer[1]);
                            v.data[2] = adjacent(v.data[0], Direction::e, v.buffer[2]);
                            v.data[3] = adjacent(v.data[1], Direction::e, v.buffer[3]);

                            return v;
                        }
                    }else{
                        // south
                        if (lon < bbox_center.lon){
                            // south west

                            v.data[1] = adjacent(v.data[0], Direction::s, v.buffer[1]);
                            v.data[2] = adjacent(v.data[0], Direction::w, v.buffer[2]);
                            v.data[3] = adjacent(v.data[1], Direction::w, v.buffer[3]);

                            return v;
                        }else{
                            // south east

                            v.data[1] = adjacent(v.data[0], Direction::s, v.buffer[1]);
                            v.data[2] = adjacent(v.data[0], Direction::e, v.buffer[2]);
                            v.data[3] = adjacent(v.data[1], Direction::e, v.buffer[3]);

                            return v;
                        }
                    }
                }

                // This still apply:
                //
                // bbox_h > 2 * radius

                // OPTIMIZED - 3 x 2 = 6

                v.size = 6;

                if (lat > bbox_center.lat){
                    // north

                    v.data[1] = adjacent(v.data[0], Direction::n, v.buffer[1]);

                    v.data[2] = adjacent(v.data[0], Direction::e, v.buffer[2]);
                    v.data[3] = adjacent(v.data[0], Direction::w, v.buffer[3]);

                    v.data[4] = adjacent(v.data[1], Direction::e, v.buffer[4]);
                    v.data[5] = adjacent(v.data[1], Direction::w, v.buffer[5]);

                    return v;
                }else{
                    // south

                    v.data[1] = adjacent(v.data[0], Direction::s, v.buffer[1]);

                    v.data[2] = adjacent(v.data[0], Direction::e, v.buffer[2]);
                    v.data[3] = adjacent(v.data[0], Direction::w, v.buffer[3]);

                    v.data[4] = adjacent(v.data[1], Direction::e, v.buffer[4]);
                    v.data[5] = adjacent(v.data[1], Direction::w, v.buffer[5]);

                    return v;
                }
            }

            if (bbox_w > 2 * radius){
                auto const bbox_center = bbox.center();

                // OPTIMIZED - 2 x 3 = 6

                // no need to check lat, it was already checked

                v.size = 6;

                if (lon < bbox_center.lon){
                    // west

                    v.data[1] = adjacent(v.data[0], Direction::w, v.buffer[1]);

                    v.data[2] = adjacent(v.data[0], Direction::n, v.buffer[2]);
                    v.data[3] = adjacent(v.data[0], Direction::s, v.buffer[3]);

                    v.data[4] = adjacent(v.data[1], Direction::n, v.buffer[4]);
                    v.data[5] = adjacent(v.data[1], Direction::s, v.buffer[5]);

                    return v;
                }else{
                    // east

                    v.data[1] = adjacent(v.data[0], Direction::e, v.buffer[1]);

                    v.data[2] = adjacent(v.data[0], Direction::n, v.buffer[2]);
                    v.data[3] = adjacent(v.data[0], Direction::s, v.buffer[3]);

                    v.data[4] = adjacent(v.data[1], Direction::n, v.buffer[4]);
                    v.data[5] = adjacent(v.data[1], Direction::s, v.buffer[5]);

                    return v;
                }

            }
        } // if constexpr(ENABLE_OPTIMIZATIONS)

        // NOT OPTIMIZED 3 x 3 = 9

        v.size = 9;

        v.data[1] = adjacent(v.data[0], Direction::n, v.buffer[1]); // n
        v.data[2] = adjacent(v.data[0], Direction::s, v.buffer[2]); // s
        v.data[3] = adjacent(v.data[0], Direction::e, v.buffer[3]); // e
        v.data[4] = adjacent(v.data[0], Direction::w, v.buffer[4]); // w

        v.data[5] = adjacent(v.data[1], Direction::e, v.buffer[5]); // ne
        v.data[6] = adjacent(v.data[1], Direction::w, v.buffer[6]); // nw

        v.data[7] = adjacent(v.data[2], Direction::e, v.buffer[7]); // se
        v.data[8] = adjacent(v.data[2], Direction::w, v.buffer[8]); // sw

        return v;
    }

    [[deprecated]]
    HashVector nearbyCells(std::string_view hash) noexcept{
        HashVector v;

        v.size = 8;

        v.data[0] = adjacent(hash,  Direction::n, v.buffer[0]); // n
        v.data[1] = adjacent(hash,  Direction::s, v.buffer[1]); // s
        v.data[2] = adjacent(hash,  Direction::e, v.buffer[2]); // e
        v.data[3] = adjacent(hash,  Direction::w, v.buffer[3]); // w

        v.data[4] = adjacent(v.data[0], Direction::e, v.buffer[4]); // ne
        v.data[5] = adjacent(v.data[0], Direction::w, v.buffer[5]); // nw

        v.data[6] = adjacent(v.data[1], Direction::e, v.buffer[6]); // se
        v.data[7] = adjacent(v.data[1], Direction::w, v.buffer[7]); // sw

        return v;
    }
}
```

---

**usage**

```
#include "geohash.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct Place{
    GeoHash::Point      point;
    std::string_view    name;
    double          supposed_distance;

    GeoHash::buffer_t   buffer;

    std::string_view    hash = GeoHash::encode(point, 12, buffer);
};

Place const places[] {
    { { 42.69210669738513, 23.32489318092748 }, "Level Up"          ,   10 },
    { { 42.69238509863727, 23.32476304836964 }, "Luchiano"          ,   42 },
    { { 42.69175842097124, 23.32523636032996 }, "Bohemian Hall"     ,   42 },
    { { 42.69269382372572, 23.32491086796810 }, "Umamido"           ,   74 },
    { { 42.69199298885176, 23.32411779452691 }, "McDonald's"        ,   74 },
    { { 42.69141486008349, 23.32517469905046 }, "Ceiba"         ,   74 },
    { { 42.69210516803149, 23.32626916568055 }, "Happy"         ,  110 },
    { { 42.69151957227103, 23.32366568780231 }, "Ugo"           ,  130 },
    { { 42.69151957227103, 23.32654779876320 }, "Il Theatro"        ,  140 },
    { { 42.69205716858902, 23.32266435016691 }, "Nicolas"           ,  200 },
    { { 42.68970992959111, 23.32455331244497 }, "Manastirska Magernitsa"    ,  300 },
    { { 42.69325388808822, 23.32118939756011 }, "The Hadjidragana Tavern"   ,  330 },
    { { 42.69174997126510, 23.32100561258516 }, "Boho"          ,  330 },
    { { 42.69205885495273, 23.33781274367048 }, "Stastlivetza"      ,  400 },
    { { 42.68999839888917, 23.31970366848597 }, "Franco's Pizza"        ,  500 },
    { { 42.69074017093236, 23.31785351529929 }, "Villa Rosiche"     ,  620 },
    { { 42.68342508736217, 23.31633975360111 }, "Chevermeto"        , 1200 }
};

constexpr GeoHash::Point me{ 42.69207945916779, 23.325029867108032 };

namespace{

    void mySearchNearby(GeoHash::Point me, double radius, GeoHash::GeoSphere const &sphere){
        auto const cells = GeoHash::nearbyCells(me, radius, sphere);

        for(auto &hash : cells){
            std::cout << "Searching cell: " << hash << '\n';

            // send query to DB
            for(auto &p : places){
                if (p.hash.size() < hash.size() || std::equal(std::begin(hash), std::end(hash), std::begin(p.hash)) == false)
                    continue;

                auto const dist = distance(me, p.point, sphere);

                if (dist > radius)
                    continue;

                std::cout << '\t' << p.name << '\t' << dist << ' ' << sphere.units << '\n';
            }
        }
    }

}

// if for some strange reason we want distances in decameters...
//constexpr auto UNITS = GeoHash::GeoSphere{ "Earth", "dm", GeoHash::EARTH_METERS.radius / 10 };
//constexpr auto UNITS = GeoHash::EARTH_YA;

constexpr auto UNITS = GeoHash::EARTH_METERS;

int main(){
    // 80 m - 3x3
    // 60 m - 2x3
    // 50 m - 2x2
    // 12 m - 3x2
    auto const radius = 80;

    mySearchNearby(me, radius, UNITS);
}
```

Comment: Was `constexpr size_t p = 1'00'000;` intentional (the second division having 2 zeroes instead of 3)?

Comment: yes, 5 zeroes. This suppose to round up the number in order to look "better"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
>     constexpr static size_t MAX_SIZE    = 12;
> ```

Misspelt `std::size_t`.  Also, most style guides reserve all-caps identifiers for macros (which don't respect namespaces, for instance).  It's quite plausible that code which includes this header also includes some library with a `MAX_SIZE` macro defined, which will cause a baffling parse error.

---

> ```
>     constexpr size_t p = 1'00'000;
> ```

This looks like a typo for `1'000'000`.  Remove the extraneous separator to prevent future maintainers attempting to correct this.

I don't like the name `_` for the approximation function.  In Python, and increasingly in C++, it's a convention for a value that is ignored.  And I think I've seen it used as a function-like macro, which again would cause a tricky error here.

It's not clear what this `fix()` function is for, especially given that `1 / 100'000` is not an exact `double` value.

It's also unclear why we're using floating-point for values evenly distributed in a small range - why not some fixed-point representation?

---

> ```
>     constexpr Point center() const{
>         return {
>             (sw.lat + ne.lat) / 2,
>             (sw.lon + ne.lon) / 2
>         };
>     }
> ```

Although overflow isn't likely with the small values we'll encounter here, it's worth being aware of `std::midpoint()` for safe mean of two values.

---

> ```
>     enum class Direction : uint8_t{
> ```

Misspelt `std::uint8_t`.

---

> ```
>     constexpr static double RADIUS_EARTH_KM     = 6371;
>     constexpr static double RADIUS_EARTH_MI     = 3956;
> ```

Apart from the all-caps naming, these are ambiguous: major or minor radius?  Are these taken from a particular geoid model?  A comment should be present here.

It's not immediately apparent what `cells` is for, nor why we need 12 of them.  That magic number `12` pops up in a few places, and it's hard to see whether all refer to the same thing.

It's probably better to initialise `cells` directly from `CELLS_ABSOLUTE` and then `std::transform` its members to do the multiplication, rather than to repeat the calculations by hand.

---

`HashVector` has the magic constant `9` with no explanation in two places.

---

> ```
>       constexpr double one_deg = M_PI / 180;
> ```

That's well-named.  But we never declared `M_PI`.  I'm guessing this is intended to be [`std::numbers::pi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/constants)?

---

> ```
> inline double Rectangle::height(GeoSphere const &sphere) const{
> //  return distance(sw.lat, sw.lon, ne.lat, sw.lon, sphere);
>     return distance(ne_p(), se_p(), sphere);
> }
>
> inline double Rectangle::width(GeoSphere const &sphere) const{
> //  return distance(sw.lat, sw.lon, sw.lat, ne.lon, sphere);
>     return distance(ne_p(), nw_p(), sphere);
> }
>
> inline double Rectangle::area(GeoSphere const &sphere) const{
>     return width(sphere) * height(sphere);
> }
> ```

Don't leave commented-out statements with no explanation.

These definitions look highly dodgy - why is `height()` measuring the *longitudinal* extent?  And `width()` a *latitudinal* one?  And the area of a Plate Carré projection has very little geodesic meaning, so what's the `area()` function for?

---

I've only glanced through the implementation file so far, but I noticed this:

> ```
>         if (border[direction][type].find(lastCh) != std::string::npos && size - 1 > 0)
> ```

The correct constant to use here would be `std::string_view::npos`.

Comment: Microsoft defines `M_PI` as a non-standard extension to `<math.h>`, and some other implementations do as well. You’re correct that `std::numbers::pi` or `std::numbers::pi_v<FLoatT>` is the standard version in C++.

Comment: With respect to `1'00'000`: is OP by any chance from South Asia? That system is in more common use there. As you say, it will confuse Westerners.

Comment: `std::numbers::pi` - this works for C++20, until then, `M_PI` is used. For MSVS, there is define that expose `M_PI` in <cmath>